# Is there a way to draw guides (lines) on-screen (windows) to aid in UI layout (just like you can in Adobe Photoshop?)

Tags: user-interface

I am wanting to draw/create guides on-screen (not within an application) that will allow me to align UI elements properly - just like you can in photoshop -- is there a tool that can do that?  Zoom would be a plus.

thank you :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd reccomend [pixelwindow](http://www.pixelwindowapp.com/) it doesn't do exactly that but it could help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Check out xScope from IconFactory. http://xscopeapp.com I use it all the time for development layouts. It's got several tools, including rulers, frames... and a "Guides" tool that is perfect for alignments and layouts. It also has a "loupe" tool, that may help with precisely aligning elements, in lieu of zooming.